# set spinner item selected value in onitemclick android

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-adapter

Hello friends i have spinner as following

[image]

When i click on any item click event than it should be set like following

[image]

it means when i select Afghnistan at that time it should be set value as AF and rest of country value remain as it is my code is as follow

**On Spinner item click**

```
mSpinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mStringCountryID=mArrayListCountryDatas.get(position).getId();

            mSpinnerCountry.setPrompt(mArrayListCountryDatas.get(position).getIso_alpha()+" 
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

When i run above code it is not set value any idea how can i make it possible ?

Comment: Where want to show selected Value. in place of `select country` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
mSpinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
            int arg2, long arg3) {
                int mStringCountryID = s1.getSelectedItemPosition(); Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "You have selected item : " + presidents[mStringCountryID], 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            } 
        });
```

Try this... variable mStringCountryID will hold your specific complete value do what ever you want to do with this value.

Comment: Khubab Hamza : i want to dispaly onitemclick as Country code is and rest of adapter should remain same as country name is ti possible with your code?